# Consulta SQL com erro em Java

Tags: java, sql, servlet

Estou tentando fazer uma webapp em java , porem sou principiante , na parte de login do app, criei uma rotina que recebe como parametro um objeto e executa uma pesquisa no banco de dados de acordo com o objeto que contem login=otavio e senha=123 .

Meu banco possui uma tabela chamada usuarios onde tem 2 campos, usuario e senha.

```
public boolean login(Cliente cliente)throws SQLException, Exception{
       String comando = "select senha from usuarios where usuario="+cliente.getLogin();       
       PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(comando);      
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
       while(rs.next()){
           if (cliente.getSenha().equals(rs.getString("senha"))){
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
    }
```

porem esta dando este erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: A coluna 'OTAVIO' não está presente em nenhuma tabela da lista FROM, ou aparece dentro de uma especificação de junção e está fora do escopo da especificação de junção, ou aparece em uma cláusula HAVING e não está na lista GROUP BY. Se esta for uma instrução CREATE ou ALTER TABLE, então, 'OTAVIO' não é uma coluna da tabela de destino.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at persistencia.Usuario.login(Usuario.java:32)
at Control.teste.main(teste.java:24)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: A coluna 'OTAVIO' não está presente em nenhuma tabela da lista FROM, ou aparece dentro de uma especificação de junção e está fora do escopo da especificação de junção, ou aparece em uma cláusula HAVING e não está na lista GROUP BY. Se esta for uma instrução CREATE ou ALTER TABLE, então, 'OTAVIO' não é uma coluna da tabela de destino.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: O erro diz que `A coluna 'OTAVIO' não está presente em nenhuma tabela da lista FROM`. Já tentou escrever a string `comando` em algum lugar do programa e executar ela em algum programa gerenciador de banco de dados?

Comment: ja e funcionou.

Answer (score 5):

Evite jogar os valores informados pelo usuário diretamente na consulta, use prepared statements para não dar chance ao sql injection. O erro aconetce porque esta faltando aspas simples em volta do valor que é retornado por `getLogin()`.

Para corrigir faça da seguinte maneira.

```
String comando = "select senha from usuarios where usuario = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(comando); 
stm.setString(1, cliente.getLogin());
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

As interrogações são trocadas pelos valores de forma sequencial se existisse mais um parâmetro ele seria o número dois e assim por diante.

Ex:

```
String comando = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario = ? AND senha = ? and token = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(comando); 
stm.setString(1, cliente.getLogin());--------------------^
stm.setString(2, cliente.getSenha());----------------------------------^
stm.setString(3, cliente.getToken());-----------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: no caso se tivessem dois valores retornados por getLogin e getQualquerCoisa. Bastaria colocar duas interrogações? por exemplo: WHERE usuario = ? AND qualquer coisa = ?

Comment: E no stm.setString setar 2 para qualquer coisa?

Comment: @JoãoNeto, seria mais ou menos isso, fique atento para usar o método `set()` com o tipo certo.

Comment: Hmmm, entendi. Muito bom, valeu =)

Answer (score 3):

O erro está aqui

```
"select senha from usuarios where usuario="+cliente.getLogin();
```

o "certo" é

```
"select senha from usuarios where usuario= '"+cliente.getLogin()+"'";
```

veja que tem uma aspa simples envolta de cliente.getLogin()

Mas nunca faça essa concatenação direta na String sql, dessa forma é muito fácil fazer um sql Injection e facilmente seu banco de dados estará em perigo.
O correto é você parametrizar os argumentos, como o colega 'Perdeu' explicou.

```
String comando = "select senha from usuarios where usuario = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(comando); 
stm.setString(1, cliente.getLogin());
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```